# How do I find unique charms in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've tried researching this one on my own and I've come up with several different answers depending on the site I'm checking. I'd like some solid information on obtaining unique charms in *Diablo 2*. There are three in total: Annihilus, Gheed's Fortune, and the Hellfire Torch.

Can I find unique charms while playing single player? If so, do they drop on a specific difficulty (Nightmare, Hell)? Details on all three would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Gheed's Fortune](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/normal/ucharms.shtml) is a random monster drop, but is a Ladder Only item.  [Here](http://diablo2.ingame.de/tips/calcs/dropcalc/dropcalc.php?lang=en&patch=110&mode=lod&interface=default&window=true) is a nice drop chance calculator for any item.  It also has some basic information about drops and Magic Find.

Both the [Annihilus](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Uber_Diablo_Quest) and [Hellfire Torch](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Pandemonium_Event) can only be found via special events on the Realms (Battle.net servers) on either Ladder or Non-Ladder, Hell Difficulty only.

Comment: It's possible to single-play through the relevant world events through the use of [mods](http://www.diablowiki.com/PlugY). As the AI scripts for the events are normally run on the server, "some restrictions apply", but it *does* make the charms available.